# What would be the best way to extract only the macro expansion language from TeX?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, tex-core

I am fond of the TeX macro language. I would like to take from TeX only the macro capabilities, that is, the expansion process, the \catcode, \def, \let, \expandafter etc., but I'm not interested in the typesetting output. In other words, I don't need the \hbox, the output routine, the glues, the pdf output etc. I need only text characters at the end of the process, which would be output in a text file.

To put flesh on bones, let me give an example:

```
   \def\foo{hello world\ }

   \let\foob=\foo

   \expandafter\def\csname foo3\endcsname {hello everybody}

   \foo \foob \csname foo3\endcsname

   \end
```

The above program would output "hello world hello world hello everybody" in a text file.

What is the simplest way to obtain the desired result?
I guess one has to cut Knuth's program just after it has totally expanded the tokens, and before it transforms them to typeset output.

Comment: it's tricky to extract from tex as it does not work in the order indicated in your final paragraph, expansion and typesetting are closely interleaved in tex's main loop. it is possible of course, latexml for example does this in perl.

Comment: in tex `\let\foo2=\foo`  would assign `\foo`  to be `2` and then typeset `=2`  is that what you want here, also you define  a command with name `foo3` but never call  it. `\foo3` is the same as `\foo  3`

Comment: if I fix `! Undefined control sequence \encsname` your test [gives this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4TDv.png) in  plain tex

Comment: I added an example that I think you intended, it typesets the text you stated if used with plain tex.

Comment: You can use \openout and \write to send expanded macros in plan text (ASCII).

Comment: @David Carlisle. Of course, you are right. This example was not supposed to be a test in any way, just a way to say what I was expecting from the macro language. So, I was careless. I have replaced my code with yours. thx.

Comment: @John Kormylo. Yes, I did perform a double input mechanism to obtain a somewhat related result. But yet, this is far to give me all the power of the language since I have to deal essentially with totally expandable macros.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your use case you may find it easier to use luatex and not use its typesetting than to really extract the expansion.

This modified version of your test produces no pdf but a text file (`\jobname` `.txt`) that contains

```
hello world hello world hello everybody
```

if used with `luatex`

---

```
\immediate\openout1\jobname.txt
\immediate\write1{
\immediateassigned{
   \def\ { }
   \def\foo{hello world\ }
   \let\foob=\foo
   \expandafter\def\csname foo3\endcsname {hello everybody}
}
   \foo \foob \csname foo3\endcsname
}

   \end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know Luatex. but I think that if used in this way, it is possible to obtain the same result with ordinary TeX. Actually, I did program a code that input the lines of code one after one, and with a double input mechanism, allows totally expandable macro to be used inside the code. So, I have exhausted this kind of solution. The problem is that I want a real typesetting interface where the user can interact with the coding as easily and as powerfully as is possible with TeX.

Comment: Also, I found your clue about Latexml interesting. I will see what I can do there.